# Why does structured binding fail on GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, structure, c++17

The following structured binding code worked well on clang. [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dsDnTuUh0ZzWmtrQ)

But, it is failed on GCC compiler. [Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wUiUoGOHHAIsa8yB)

```
#include <iostream>

struct st {
  bool b = true;
};

template <class T>
bool func() noexcept {
  auto [a] = T{};
  return a;
}

int main() {
  const bool b1 = func<st>();
}
```

Why does structured binding fail on GCC?

Comment: WHat is expected result, what is actual result?

Comment: Because GCC had a bug in its implementation that needs fixing. That's the answer to the question you asked. It's not an overly useful question. You could however rephrase it in order to make it more useful.

Comment: This question is... eerily closely related to the gcc bug?

Comment: The compiler says „failed“?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81888) that was introduced in GCC 7.2. Your code is standard compliant.